# On the fly PVRTC compression on iOS

Tags: ios, compression, textures

I'm writing an iPhone app that is quite heavy on GPU memory. Some of the textures are created procedurally by the app, which means that I cannot compress them to PVRTC to decrease their on-GPU size (and thus memory).
Does anyone know of a library that does this?
The closest I found was PVRTexLib ( http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtexlib.asp ) but that is for MacOSX, and not iOS.

I found this question which is similar : [Convert .png to PVRTC *on* the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020944/convert-png-to-pvrtc-on-the-iphone) but they took it to a different direction (on why you shouldn't want to do it).
However, my app uses OpenGL so I do benefit greatly from being able to use PVRTC.

Does anyone know of such a library?

Comment: When you say "procedurally" do you mean something along the lines of, say, Perlin texture synthesis or something simpler like assembly of a dynamic texture atlas?

Comment: We take a picture and apply some color manipulation to it. We have many manipulations available and can't afford to ship all of the results with the application (size constraints) so we do it procedurally at runtime

Comment: Ahh, now that sounds feasible. If you are only doing, say, linear transforms or simple changes on the colour (e.g replacing colours of uniforms etc) you could probably do that directly on the compressed format.

Answer (score 0):

PVRTexTool from Imagination includes an SDK and a pre-compiled library for a number of platforms, including arm. That should be linkable to an iPhone executable.

https://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/tools/pvrtextool/

However, maybe more interestingly, can you write shaders that re-map the colors as needed? You don't need to re-compress the texture, or change the bits of it at all, if you can apply the function you need in a shader.